# Matplotlib: keep grid lines behind the graph but the y and x axis above

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having a hard time plotting grid lines under my graphs without messing with the main x and y axis zorder:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
menStd =   (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd, alpha=0.9, linewidth = 0,zorder=3)

womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
womenStd =   (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='y', yerr=womenStd, alpha=0.9, linewidth = 0,zorder=3)

# add some
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5') )

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women') )

fig.gca().yaxis.grid(True, which='major', linestyle='-', color='#D9D9D9',zorder=2, alpha = .9)
[line.set_zorder(4) for line in ax.lines]

def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

The example is taken from matplotlib's own, and I have tweaked a little to show how to make the problem appear. I cannot post images but if you run  the code you will see that the bars are plotted above the horizontal grid lines as well as above the x and y axis. I do not want the x and y axis being hidden by the graph, especially when the ticks are also getting blocked.

Comment: why do you use `fig.gca()` instead of `ax`?

Comment: out of curiosity: do you know what creates the lines in `ax.lines`?

Comment: You are right, I was just lost trying to figure out how to do it instead of trying to understand how everything works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried matplotlib 1.2.1, 1.3.1rc2 and master (commit 06d014469fc5c79504a1b40e7d45bc33acc00773)

To get the axis spines on top of the the bars you can do the following:

```
for k, spine in ax.spines.items():  #ax.spines is a dictionary
    spine.set_zorder(10)
```

**EDIT**

It seems that I can't make the tick lines to go on top of the bars. I've tried

```
1. ax.tick_params(direction='in', length=10, color='k', zorder=10)
   #This increases the size of the lines to 10 points, 
   #but the lines stays hidden behind  the bars
2. for l in ax.yaxis.get_ticklines():
       l.set_zorder(10)
```

and some other way with no results. It seems that when drawing the bars they are put on top and the zorder is ignored

A workaround could be to draw the tick lines outwards

```
ax.tick_params(direction='out', length=4, color='k', zorder=10)
```

or both in and outwards, using `direction='inout'`

**EDIT2**

I've done some test after @tcaswell comments.

If `zorder` in the `ax.bar` function is set to be <=2, the axis, ticklines *and* grid lines are drawn above the bars. If the valus is >2.01 (the default value for axis) the bars are drawn on top of the axis, ticklines and grid. Then it possible to set larger values to the spines (as above) but any attempt to change the `zorder` of the ticklines is simply ignored (although the values are updated on the corresponding artists).

I've tried the to use `zorder=1` for the `bar` and `zorder=0` for the grid and the grid is drawn **on top** of the bars. So zorder is ignored.

**recap**

It seems to me that ticklines and grid `zorder` are just ignored and kept to the default values. For me this is a bug somehow related with `bar` or some `patches`.

BTW, I do remember changing successfully the zorder in ticklines when using `imshow`

Comment: that sounds like a bug, can you check if it also happen on master?

Comment: I give a try and let you know

Comment: @tcaswell I've tried on 1.3.1rc2 and master (just fetched) and does not work. It's a bug then. Who files it? [I can try to give a look at the source code later today if I find any hint about the problem]

Comment: actually, I think this is more of a 'feature' than a bug as the grid lines inherit their z order from the axis objects.

Comment: try making the zorder of your bar graph negative.

Comment: @tcaswell: if I put `-3` the grid and the ticklines are above. Are you saying that either grids **and** ticklines are above or below the bars? I'm fine if this is the default, but you should be able to change it if needed.

Comment: @tcaswell the fact that it inherits the zorder  from the axis object should not mean that I cannot change it. That is what I am trying to do in ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='major', linestyle='-', color='#D9D9D9',zorder=2, alpha = .9)

Comment: @luke_16 iirc the tick lines + axes are drawn in one shot by the renderers so they _can't_ have different zorders.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem of axes getting drawn below the plot line when I have grid lines in the background:

```
ax.yaxis.grid()  # grid lines
ax.set_axisbelow(True)  # grid lines are behind the rest
```

The solution that worked for me was to set the `zorder` argument of the `plot()` function to a value between 1 and 2. It is not immediately clear, but the zorder value can be any number. From the documentation for the [`matplotlib.artist.Artist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder) class:

> **set_zorder(level)**
>
> Set the zorder for the artist. Artists with lower zorder values are drawn first.
>
> ACCEPTS: any number

Therefore:

```
for i in range(5):
    ax.plot(range(10), np.random.randint(10, size=10), zorder=i / 100.0 + 1)
```

I haven't checked for values outside this range, maybe they would also work.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite an old question but the problem seems to essentially remain, so let me write down an MRE and my solution with Python 3.9.6 and Matplotlib 3.4.2.

**Problem**

As the OP was aware, the default `zorder` for bar plots is relatively low.
The following code leads to a plot where both the tick lines and the grid lines are above the bars.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
x = range(len(y))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y)
ax.grid(True)
ax.tick_params(direction="in", length=10)

plt.show()
```

[image: First example]

It is possible to use `ax.set_axisbelow(True)` to move both the tick lines and the grid lines behind the bars, but then the ticks on the x-axis are hidden by the bars.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
x = range(len(y))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y)
ax.grid(True)
ax.tick_params(direction="in", length=10)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)  # This line added.

plt.show()
```

[image: Second example]

**Solution**

Redraw the tick lines after all elements in the plot are drawn.
(I assume they are opaque and the redrawing is harmless.)

```py
import matplotlib.artist
import matplotlib.backend_bases
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class TickRedrawer(matplotlib.artist.Artist):
    """Artist to redraw ticks."""

    __name__ = "ticks"

    zorder = 10

    @matplotlib.artist.allow_rasterization
    def draw(self, renderer: matplotlib.backend_bases.RendererBase) -> None:
        """Draw the ticks."""
        if not self.get_visible():
            self.stale = False
            return

        renderer.open_group(self.__name__, gid=self.get_gid())

        for axis in (self.axes.xaxis, self.axes.yaxis):
            loc_min, loc_max = axis.get_view_interval()

            for tick in axis.get_major_ticks() + axis.get_minor_ticks():
                if tick.get_visible() and loc_min <= tick.get_loc() <= loc_max:
                    for artist in (tick.tick1line, tick.tick2line):
                        artist.draw(renderer)

        renderer.close_group(self.__name__)
        self.stale = False


y = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
x = range(len(y))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y)
ax.grid(True)
ax.tick_params(direction="in", length=10)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.add_artist(TickRedrawer())  # This line added.

plt.show()
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of plotting above the axes as @luke_16. In my case, it arose when using the option `ax.set_axisbelow(True)` to set the grind behind the plots.

My workaround for this bug is, not to use the onboard-grid, but to simulate it:

```
def grid_selfmade(ax,minor=False):
    y_axis=ax.yaxis.get_view_interval()
    for xx in ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs():
        ax.plot([xx,xx],y_axis,linestyle=':',linewidth=0.5,zorder=0)
    if minor==True:
        for xx in ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs(minor=True):
            ax.plot([xx,xx],y_axis,linestyle=':',linewidth=0.5,zorder=0)
    x_axis=ax.xaxis.get_view_interval()
    for yy in ax.yaxis.get_ticklocs():
        ax.plot(x_axis,[yy,yy],linestyle=':',linewidth=0.5,zorder=0,)
    if minor==True:
        for yy in ax.yaxis.get_ticklocs(minor=True):
            ax.plot(x_axis,[yy,yy],linestyle=':',linewidth=0.5,zorder=0)
```

This function only needs the current axis-instance and then draws an onboard-like grid *behind everything else* at the major ticks (optional also for minor ticks).

For having the axis and axis ticks on top of the graphs, it is necessary to leave `ax.set_axisbelow(False)` to `False` and not to use `zorder`>2 in plots. I managed the zorder of plots without any `zorder`-option by changing the order of plot-commands in code.

Answer (score 1):

A easier and better solution is to copy the lines from the grid command and disable the grid and again add the lines again but with correct zorder:

```
ax.grid(True)
lines = ax.xaxis.get_gridlines().copy() + ax.yaxis.get_gridlines().copy()
ax.grid(False)
for l in lines:
    ax.add_line(l)
    l.set_zorder(0)
```

Comment: I don't understand what ax1 is in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

borrowing from @tueda's MRE...

This produces the undesired result of the grid lines over the bars. As the question points out, increasing the bar zorder places the bars over the axis ticks.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
x = range(len(y))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y)
ax.grid(True)
ax.tick_params(direction="in", length=10)
```

[image]

**Solution**: Manually plot horizontal and vertical lines for each tick *under* the bar instead of using `grid()`...

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
x = range(len(y))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y)
ax.tick_params(direction="in", length=10)

for i in ax.get_xticks():
    ax.axvline(i, color="g", zorder=-10)
for i in ax.get_yticks():
    ax.axhline(i, color="r", zorder=-10)
```

[image]