# matplotlib zorder of elements in polar plot superimposed on cartesian plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, z-order, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I'm having a difficulty controlling the zorder of the elements of a polar plot superimposed on a cartesian plot.

Consider this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(1, 1, marker='*', s=2000, c='r', zorder=2)
ax2 = fig.add_axes(ax.get_position(), frameon=False, polar=True)
ax2.scatter(1., 0.1, marker='*', s=1000, c='b', zorder=1)
plt.xlim(0, 2)
plt.ylim(0, 2)
plt.show()
```

The result is:
[image]

It looks like `matplotlib` ignored the `zorder` of scatter plots. I would expect the red star to be on top of the blue one.

Could you please explain what I'm doing wrong here?

I found [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677963/matplotlib-keep-grid-lines-behind-the-graph-but-the-y-and-x-axis-above), which is kind of similar to mine, but concerns ticklines and grids instead. Maybe it's the same bug?

P.S. I'm running Linux x86_64 with Python 2.7.6 and matplotlib 1.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the z-order of the marks on different axes `ax` and `ax2` but since `ax2` has a greater z-order all the plots in it will be on top of `ax`. One solution could be to set a higher z-order to `ax` but then you need to make the background transparent or set `frameon=False` (and that's maybe not desirable for your case), this is a demonstration of what I'm saying:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.scatter(1, 1, marker='*', s=2000, c='r', zorder=2)

ax2 = fig.add_axes(ax.get_position(), frameon=False, polar=True)
ax2.scatter(1., 0.1, marker='*', s=1000, c='b', zorder=1)

ax.set_zorder(3)
ax.patch.set_facecolor('none')
#ax.patch.set_visible(False)

plt.xlim(0, 2)
plt.ylim(0, 2)
plt.show()
```

Plot:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a good documentation on how zorder is handled in matplotlib. For example, is there such a thing as cross-axes zorder? The problem is that the background of my ax is indeed not transparent. I guess I can plot the red star on ax2, but the coordinates become polar and positioning and scaling becomes awkward.